# How do you update the R version in Revolution R Enterprise?

Tags: r, revolution-r

I just installed the latest MRO version (3.2.3)

When I open RGui, I see the following

```
 R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree" Copyright (C)
 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform:
 x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

However when I open up Revolution R Enterprise, I see that 3.2.2 is still loaded

```
Welcome to Revolution R Enterprise for Windows version 8.0 - 100% R and more...
Revolution R Enterprise for Windows Copyright © 2015 Microsoft Corporation
---------------------------------------------------------------------
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
```

How do I change this so that Revolution R Enterprise points to 3.2.3 instead of 3.2.2

I did a search here and on Google/Bing but found nothing.

Comment: my guess would be that you have to [download a new version of RRE](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/download/)

Comment: @BenBolker That is the download I already have, in R Open I see 3.2.3.  In RRE I see 3.2.2..... Checking on MSDN, the RRE version that is there is the one I downloaded in January... But there should be a way to target a different versions of R from within RRE.. but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't, at least not currently. RRE versions are tied to specific R version. 8.0 corresponds to 3.2.2.

Comment: There must be a way to save Revo R Ent from the slavery of Microsoft. Many think MS's take over Revo Analytics damaged "Revo R Ent"!

Comment: Not sure about saving it from Microsoft slavery, but you have never been able change the underlying version of R even prior to Microsoft acquisition.